Ruby on Rails, threading in DelayedJob workers
I'm working on a Ruby on Rails web project that runs on Puma server, also has several DelayedJob Workers on different servers.
The project generates some special logs that i want to send to AWS Sqs queue. Those logs are generated on both, frontend requests (run in the Puma server) and in different Delayed Jobs run in the Delayed::Worker servers.
One prerequisite is to send this information asyncronously son i've implemented a SQSManager class where different threads can write to a temporal local Queue (thread safe), and a second thread processes them every 10 seconds. This thread is launched on puma and workers start.
The relevant code is similar to this:
require 'aws-sdk-sqs'

class SQSManager
  SEND_INTERVAL = 10 # seconds
  MAX_BATCH_SIZE = 10000

  @@sqs_queue_url = APP_CONFIG[:aws_sqs_queue_url]
  @@local_queue = Queue.new # Threadsafe intermediate buffer
  @@sqs_client = Aws::SQS::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION']) if ENV['AWS_REGION']
  @@worker_thread = nil

  # Add a log to the local queue
  def self.add_log(log)
      Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): adding log, current # elements #{@@local_queue}"
      @@local_queue << cal
    end
  end

  def self.start
    @@worker_thread = Thread.new do
      Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): Starting thread"
      loop do
        sleep(SEND_INTERVAL)
        send_messages
        if @@local_queue.empty?
          Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): Stopping thread"
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def self.send_messages
    Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): processing local queues"
    if @@local_queue.empty?
      Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): Messages empty"
    else
      Rails.logger.warn "SQSManager (#{$$}): Sending messages"
      MAX_BATCH_SIZE.times do
        unless @@local_queue.empty?
          begin
            @@sqs_client.send_message({queue_url: sqs_queue_url, message_body: @@local_queue.pop})
          rescue Aws::SQS::Errors::ServiceError => e
            Rails.logger.error "SQSManager (#{$$}): Error sending messages to #{sqs_queue_url}: #{e.message}.\nBacktrace:\n\t#{e.backtrace.join("\n\t")}"
          end
        else
          break
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

On puma i've configured to start the SQSManager thread on the after_fork hook and everything works fine. But with the DelayedJob i'm able to launch this thread, but something weird happens. It seems that the DelayedJob threads write on the local queue but the sending to SQS thread finds the local queue empty.
The log looks like this:
SQSManager (15928): Starting thread
SQSManager (15928): adding log, current # elements 0
SQSManager (15928): adding log, current # elements 1
SQSManager (15928): processing local queues
SQSManager (15928): Messages empty
SQSManager (15928): processing local queues
SQSManager (15928): Messages empty
SQSManager (15928): adding log, current # elements 0
SQSManager (15928): processing local queues
SQSManager (15928): Messages empty

Looks like the concrete job can write to the local queue but it 'disapears' later. Maybe every job execution has its own SQSManager class with its queue and it's destroyed when the job ends?
The initializer for starting SQSManager on the Delaye::Worker it's a bit tricky but it's the best i found to make SQSManager thread run:
#config/initializer/delayed_job_worker.rb
require 'delayed_job'

module DelayedJobWorker

  def self.included(base)

    base.class_eval do
      alias_method :original_stop, :stop
      alias_method :original_start, :start

      def start
        Delayed::Worker.logger.warn "original_start worker!"
        SQSManager.start # SQSManager initialization before the Workr original start
        original_start
      end

      def stop
        SQSManager.shutdown
        original_stop
      end
    end
  end
end

Delayed::Worker.include(DelayedJobWorker)

I think the key is in this initializer and also has tried many different things but i cant make it work properly. Any suggestions?
Technical data: Ruby 3.3, Rails 4.2.11.36 LTS, DelayedJob 4.1.11.

Finally y managed to fix this issue. The solution was very easy, simply transform SQSManager to a singleton. The problem came for mixing contexts and threads initializations:
require 'singleton'

class SQSManager
   include Singleton

   ...
  def initialize
    @sqs_queue_url = APP_CONFIG[:aws_sqs_queue_url]
    @local_queue = Queue.new # Threadsafe intermediate buffer
    @sqs_client = Aws::SQS::Client.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION']) if ENV['AWS_REGION']
    @worker_thread = nil
    start_worker_thread
  end
  
  # The rest of method change from static to instance methods.

And the use of SQSManager is almost equal, ie:
SQSManager.instance.start or SQSManager.instance.stop 

